# How can I build multiple submit buttons django form?

Tags: python, django, button, django-forms, submit

I have form with one input for email and two submit buttons to subscribe and unsubscribe from newsletter:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{{ form_newsletter }}
<input type="submit" name="newsletter_sub" value="Subscribe" />
<input type="submit" name="newsletter_unsub" value="Unsubscribe" />
</form>
```

I have also class form:

```
class NewsletterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Newsletter
        fields = ('email',)
```

I must write my own clean_email method and I need to know by which button was form submited. But the value of submit buttons aren't in `self.cleaned_data` dictionary.
Could I get values of buttons otherwise?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can use `self.data` in the `clean_email` method to access the POST data before validation. It should contain a key called `newsletter_sub` or `newsletter_unsub` depending on which button was pressed.

```
# in the context of a django.forms form

def clean(self):
    if 'newsletter_sub' in self.data:
        # do subscribe
    elif 'newsletter_unsub' in self.data:
        # do unsubscribe
```

Comment: can you give an annotated example? it'd really help

Comment: I don't think `clean` isn't really the right kind of place to do model-level logic. It's specifically for cleaning a form and finding any `ValidationError`s that span multiple inputs. Sven's answer is more in the right direction, but still not necessarily the best answer

Comment: Security Risk! Using form data to make changes in the database before the form has been validated is dangerous.

Comment: You may want to run different types of validation depending on which button was pressed. In that case, there is no "Security" impact.

Comment: How would you test this using `TestCase.client.post`?

Answer (score 290):

Eg:

```
if 'newsletter_sub' in request.POST:
    # do subscribe
elif 'newsletter_unsub' in request.POST:
    # do unsubscribe
```

Comment: Is request available inside the clean_xxx validation methods?

Comment: In what method should this go?

Comment: @JonMcClung Inside `def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Override `ModelAdmin._changeform_view` if you want it Admin native with authentication.

Comment: THANK YOU @Damon from 13 years ago!!! I've been working on this for hours. This is so elegant and simple.

Answer (score 39):

You can also do like this,

```
 <form method='POST'>
    {{form1.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" name="btnform1">Save Changes</button>
    </form>
    <form method='POST'>
    {{form2.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" name="btnform2">Save Changes</button>
    </form>
```

***CODE***

```
if request.method=='POST' and 'btnform1' in request.POST:
    do something...
if request.method=='POST' and 'btnform2' in request.POST:
    do something...
```

Comment: form1.as_p when to use this?? in the views, while checking validity of form, I wish I could do... form1.is_valid() then do this, form2.is_valid() do this..

Answer (score 8):

one url to the same view! 
like so!

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.landing.as_view(), name = 'landing'),
```

views.py

```
class landing(View):
        template_name = '/home.html'
        form_class1 = forms.pynamehere1
        form_class2 = forms.pynamehere2
            def get(self, request):
                form1 = self.form_class1(None)
                form2 = self.form_class2(None)
                return render(request, self.template_name, { 'register':form1, 'login':form2,})

             def post(self, request):
                 if request.method=='POST' and 'htmlsubmitbutton1' in request.POST:
                        ## do what ever you want to do for first function ####
                 if request.method=='POST' and 'htmlsubmitbutton2' in request.POST:
                         ## do what ever you want to do for second function ####
                        ## return def post###  
                 return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form,})
```

```
/home.html
    <!-- #### form 1 #### -->
    <form action="" method="POST" >
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ register.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" name="htmlsubmitbutton1">Login</button>
    </form>
    <!--#### form 2 #### -->
    <form action="" method="POST" >
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ login.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" name="htmlsubmitbutton2">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: how should i refer to particular view from other html files href = "{% url 'appname:viewname' %}"

Comment: what should i give for form in views.py

Comment: Why are you testing if the method is POST in the post function? Class based views only call post function if the http method is POST.

Comment: I can't seem to remember as to why seeing as this was 4 years ago. However, I seemed to recall that this was necessary because of a circular action method with one form being submitted and not the other. Not entirely sure though.

Answer (score 5):

It's an old question now, nevertheless I had the same issue and found a solution that works for me: I wrote MultiRedirectMixin.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class MultiRedirectMixin(object):
    """
    A mixin that supports submit-specific success redirection.
     Either specify one success_url, or provide dict with names of 
     submit actions given in template as keys
     Example: 
       In template:
         <input type="submit" name="create_new" value="Create"/>
         <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
       View:
         MyMultiSubmitView(MultiRedirectMixin, forms.FormView):
             success_urls = {"create_new": reverse_lazy('create'),
                               "delete": reverse_lazy('delete')}
    """
    success_urls = {}  

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """ Form is valid: Pick the url and redirect.
        """

        for name in self.success_urls:
            if name in form.data:
                self.success_url = self.success_urls[name]
                break

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        """
        Returns the supplied success URL.
        """
        if self.success_url:
            # Forcing possible reverse_lazy evaluation
            url = force_text(self.success_url)
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                _("No URL to redirect to. Provide a success_url."))
        return url
```

Comment: Where and how exactly will you use MultiRedirectMixin? Please elaborate with an example.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but some of the answers are, to say the least, brief, and they do not address a common case where the form is not a django form.

This solution was inspired by [this blog post](https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/having-multiple-submit-buttons-for-same-form-in-django/). It relies on using a view class that is derived from django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin, e.g. CreateView, UpdateView or DeleteView. These provide the *get_success_url* method which exposes the button name in *request*

**html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <div>
                <label> <input type="radio" name="select-type" value="A">Type A</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label> <input type="radio" name="select-type" value="B">Type B</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Use selected">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="no-selection" value="None of the above">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class GetType(UpdateView):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'get_type.html', {})

    def post(self, request):
        button = self.get_success_url()
        print(button)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if 'no-selection' in self.request.POST:
            return 'none selected'
        return ''
```