# how do you doing for autocomplete one form from database for update information in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, forms, web

views.py

```
def editarmission(request):


   if request.method=="POST":       
      formulariomission = FormMission()
      if formulariomission.is_valid():
         formulariomission.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/albatrosmt/misiones')
   else:
      formulariomission = FormMission()
      return render(request,'editarmission.html',{'formulariomission_template':formulariomission})
```

and formularios.py

```
class FormMission(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = bd_mission
        fields = ('missionname','dispositivos_id', 'commits')
```

My question is how i can introduce the information from database into input's form, for edit this database lane, only pick one lane and change data.

database lane --> form autocomplete--> edit data --> update database with changes

PD: sorry for my bad english and thanks bro's

Comment: If 1 Form + 2 Models:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770810/multiple-models-in-a-single-django-modelform

elif 2 form + models:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758330/how-insert-2-different-forms-on-the-same-page-in-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate form data from database you should pass `instance` argument to form's constructor:

```
def editarmission(request, mission_id):
   mission = get_object_or_404(bd_mission, pk=mission_id)
   if request.method == "POST":       
      formulariomission = FormMission(request.POST, instance=mission)
      if formulariomission.is_valid():
         formulariomission.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/albatrosmt/misiones')
   else:
      formulariomission = FormMission(instance=mission)
      return render(request,'editarmission.html', 'formulariomission_template':formulariomission})
```