# django 2 user edit and change password forms on the same page

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a user profile page where I want to have two forms:
- user info edit form
- password change form

Currently I do have two separate pages with separate views.
For password change I'm using django's contrib auth provided views and forms.

I want to be able to put this two forms into a single page and be able to either change user data or password.

Any idea how this is best achieved ? What is the elegant way of doing this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How insert 2 different forms on the same page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758330/how-insert-2-different-forms-on-the-same-page-in-django)

Comment: Duplicate:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758330/how-insert-2-different-forms-on-the-same-page-in-django][1]