# Key error in Django on form with prefix

Tags: python, django, forms, cleaned-data

I am using two forms on one page (I have my reasons). They are not model forms. I am trying to validate them by using prefix. I found it here: [Proper way to handle multiple forms on one page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django)
But when I try to get cleaned_data, i get key error.
Here is some of my code:

```
add_form = AbsenceTypeForm(request.POST, prefix = 'atype')
if add_form.is_valid():
    absence_type = AbsenceType(
        client = client_instance,
        name = add_form.cleaned_data['type_name'],
        gainful = add_form.cleaned_data['gainful'],
    )
    absence_type.save()
```

And I get KeyError for type_name. I tried to add `cleaned_data['atype-type_name']` - nothing helps.

Comment: try `cleaned_data.get('foo')`

Comment: Try printing request.POST and see what values you have. I"m sure you'll see the collection you're trying to reference by key.

Answer (score 2):

What about dumping the cleaned_data somewhere, to a screen or a file  - just to check the keys it gets? Debugger should also show the dictionary in the locals. I would guess it's either lost / misspelled prefix or the form field name.

Btw I agree that using .get() is safer (even though it looks like the form validation should be already handled by is_valid(), however you might decide to change the field to be non-mandatory in the future and then this code would error), so:

```
name = add_form.cleaned_data.get('type_name',None),
gainful = add_form.cleaned_data.get('gainful',None),

if name and gainful:
    pass
    #rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks. This is much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you left `type_name` empty in your posted form; `cleaned_data` only contains keys for non-empty form fields.