# Is it possible to POST to a different Django view?

Tags: django

I'm trying to render two forms (signup and login) on the same page in Django. I want to POST the data to either field by changing the `<form action="some_url"` tag. It's the first suggestion in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395866/2532070

Is this possible? Currently I have:

urls.py:

```
url(r'^', HomePageView.as_view()),
url(r'^signup/$', SignupUser.as_view(), name="signup_user"),
```

views.py:

```
class HomePageView(View):
    template_name = "index.html"

    login_form = AuthenticationForm()
    signup_form = UserCreationForm()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'login_form': self.login_form, 
            'signup_form': self.signup_form,
            'signup_action': reverse("signup_user")} 
        )

class SignupUser(CreateView):
    model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    form_class = UserCreationForm
```

my template:

```
<form action="{{ signup_action }}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ signup_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Signup">
</form>
```

Unfortunately, the POST seems to be calling the post function of `HomePageView`, rather than calling the `SignupUser` view.

Is it possible to call my SignupUser view with the POST data by correctly formatting my form's `action="..."` tags?

Comment: Of course it's possible: this is just standard HTML behaviour. Can you check (via View Source) that the action attribute is getting correctly populated?

Comment: Thanks Daniel! It loads as action="/signup/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not where you think it is.

The issue is that your initial URL, which points at HomePageView, catches *everything*, because you do not specify the end of the string. You have a start anchor, `^`, but not an end anchor, which means it basically matches "every string that starts", ie everything.

You need to only match the empty string:

```
url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view()),
```