# How can I handle Django login and signup on the same page with class based views?

Tags: django

I want to create one page with both a login and signup form. Per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395866/2532070, the best way is to use a separate `<form action="{{url}}"` tag for each form, and use two different views to handle the `POST` data for each form. My problem is that using the same view would allow me to pass the errors back to the forms, but if I use separate views with separate urls, I have to redirect the user back to the original page and add these parameters as part of a query string, which doesn't seem very efficient.

My Urls:

```
url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name="home_page"),
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', MemberUpdate.as_view(template_name="profile.html"), name="profile_page"),
url(r'^signup/$', SignupUser.as_view(), name="signup_user"),
```

My views:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    login_form = AuthenticationForm()
    signup_form = UserCreationForm()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['login_form'] = self.login_form
        context['signup_form'] = self.signup_form
        context['signup_action'] = reverse("signup_user")
        return context

class SignupUser(CreateView):
    model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    form_class = MemberForm
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("profile_page", args=[self.object.pk])

    def form_invalid(self, form):

        # here, how do I pass form.errors back to the home_page?
        # I know messages framework is possible but this isn't as
        # easy to add each error to its respective field as 
        # form.errors would be.

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_page'))
```

...and I would have a third view for the login form's `POST` data. Is this an acceptable way to manage my forms/views, or am I better off simply writing one overall view that distinguishes between the signup and login form within its `post` method with an `if` statment?