# Django 1.6.1: Two apps, two model forms, one template. Why does is_valid fail?

Tags: python, django

is valid always fails, what am i doing wrong?

error.html keeps getting triggered

any help would be appreciated

filler stuff filler stufffiller stuff filler stufffiller stuff filler stuff

---

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from user_profile.models import UserProfile
from forms import UserProfileForm

from drinker.models import Drinker
from drinker.forms import RegistrationForm


from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

@login_required
def your_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formBio = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        formDrinker = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if formBio.is_valid() and formDrinker.is_valid():
            userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            bio = form.cleaned_data['bio']
            userProfile.bio = bio

            userDrinker = Drinker.objects.get(user=request.user)
            birthday = form.cleaned_data['birthday']
            userDrinker.birthday = birthday
            userDrinker.save()

            userDrinker = Drinker.objects.get(user=request.user)
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            userDrinker.name = name
            userDrinker.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/profile/' + str(userProfile.id))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/error/')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/update_profile')
```

Comment: You are processing two forms at once? This should not work, there should be one transmitted on send only.

Answer (score 0):

Your POST request contains two forms. You need to tell Django what POST data correspond to what form. You can use the `prefix` argument in your forms.

See [Proper way to handle multiple forms on one page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django) and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms.