# Form Field not displaying in Template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to Django and am having a bit of trouble with forms. I'm trying to display a single text input so that users can enter their phone number and it will be sent to my email. I'm actually going to have it stored in a postgre database but want to get the basics down first. The submit button is being displayed but the text input field isn't. I tried putting the forms.py inside of the views.py to see if the PhoneForm() function and file wasn't importing but that didn't do anything.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from .forms import PhoneForm

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    # Render the index.html template with a context dictionary
    return render(request, "index.html")

def get_number(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #create a form instance
        form = PhoneForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            send_mail(
                cd['phone_form'],
                ['siteadmin@example.com'],
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = PhoneForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

index.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class PhoneForm(forms.Form):
    phone_form = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

EDIT: Adding urls.py (the one in the app)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.get_number, name='get_number'),
]
```

Comment: can you show urls.py?

Comment: @vadimchin ahhh I forgot about those.. Added. I wonder if there's something wrong with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both urls in `urls.py` have the same expression `r'^$'` and django looks for them in order, therefore the first one (index) will always be selected. This links to the index view not the get_number view. This means the form is not passed to the template and the form does not show up.

To solve this move `url(r'^$', get_number),` to the top of 'urlpatterns'.

Comment: this worked! Thank you! I'm confused on one thing... does this mean that every page can only have 1 "view"? How do you implement multiple forms then in a single page? I always thought that "views" were just a certain part of the page but it looks like it's the entire thing...

Comment: Yeah views are the entire page. To implement more than 1 form set 2 forms  `form1 = PhoneForm()` and `form2 = PhoneForm()` in the view then call them in the template `{{ form1 }}` and `{{ form2 }}` inside different HTML forms. Then put `name=form1submit` in the `<submit>` button for first form (and do same for second) and then in view `if request.method == 'POST'` and `if 'form1submit' in request.post` perform actions for the first form `elif 'form2submit in request.post` perform actions for second form. More details can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/

Answer (score 0):

Change from {{form}} to {{form.phone_form}} in index.html

Comment: No change :C Interestingly, just being on the page, when I try to refresh, I get a google chrome error saying "confirm form resubmission. The page that you're looking for used information you entered" even though there is no visible form