# How can I tell in my django view, which of the 2 forms' fields were filled?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to display both `form1` and `form2` on a web page. If `form2` is filled (`if success == True`), I want my view to not execute    `if form1.is_valid:`

(which gives errors). How can I access the value of `success` in views.py?

forms.py

```
class Form1(forms.Form):
    ....
    ....
    def clean(self):
        ....
        ....

class Form2(forms.Form):
    ....
    ....
    def clean(self):
        ....
        success = False
```

views.py

```
def my_view(request, element_pk):
    ....
    ....
    if request.method == POST:
        form2 = Form2(request.POST)
        form1 = Form1(request.POST)

    if form2.is_valid():
        ....
    if form1.is_valid():
        ....

    else:
        form2 = Form2()
        form1 = Form1()
```

Comment: You may need to take a look of the answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django).

Comment: @AbzRockers There is only one Submit button in the template file that my view renders.

Answer (score 0):

For your `<input />` or `<button></button>` tag, use a `name` parameter for each form (i.e.):

```
<button type="submit" name="form_1">Go!</button>
```

Then, in your view, do something like:

```
if form2.is_valid() and 'form_2' in request.POST:
    . . .
if form1.is_valid() and 'form_1' in request.POST:
    . . .
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention it. There can't be separate buttons.

Comment: @amateur_coder You could also have two separate action url's on your form, with a different view handling each form.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `success = False` as you've done in the clean method only sets it locally. Store the value on the class (`self.success = False`) or in the cleaned_data (`self.cleaned_data['success'] = False`, assuming your form has no field called success).

Then, you can access the value with:

```
if form2.is_valid():
    success = form2.success
```

or

```
if form2.is_valid():
    success = form2.cleaned_data.get('success')
```

For more information about the `clean` function, see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).