# how to get information the two (csrf_token) in same page

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two forms, but i need get information the first form but i dont know how to make

Is django 1.11 and python 2.7

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Administrador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/estilo-competencias.css">
</head>

<body>


    <div class="container-alumnos">
        <form action="/seleccion" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <select id="carrera" name="Carrera">
                    <option value="1">TICS</option>
                    <option value="2">Carrera</option>
                    <option value="3">Carrera</option>
                    <option value="4">Carrera</option>
                    <option value="5">Carrera</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <select id="Alumno" name="Nombre">

                    {% if alumno|length > 1 %}
                    {% for alumno in alumno %}
                    <option value="{{alumno.idAlumnos}}">{{alumno.nombre}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                    <option value="{{alumno.idAlumnos}}">{{alumno.nombre}}</option>
                    {%endif%}

                    <input type="submit" name="Seleccionar">

                </select>
            </div>
            <label for="ID">ID</label>
            <input type="input" name="id" disabled value="{{alumno.idAlumnos}}"><br>
            <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
            <input type="input" name="apellidos" disabled value="{{alumno.apellidos}}"><br>
            <label for="Correo">Correo</label>
            <input type="input" name="Correo" disabled value="{{alumno.correo}}"><br>

        </form>

    </div>

    <select id="opciones" name="Semana">
        <option value="1">Semana 1</option>
        <option value="2">Semana 2</option>
        <option value="3">Semana 3</option>
        <option value="4">Semana 4</option>
        <option value="5">Semana 5</option>
    </select>
    <div class="container-listas">


        <select id="competencias" name="competencia">
            {% for comp in competencias %}
            <option value="{{comp.idCompetencias}}">{{comp.nombre}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <div class="Container-listas-enviar">
            <form action="/evidences" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="Nivel-bajo">Bajo</label>
                <input type="radio" name="bajo" ><br>
                <label for="medio">Medio</label>
                <input type="radio" name="medio" ><br>
                <label for="Alto">Alto</label>
                <input type="radio" name="Alto" ><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

when i press Enviar in the second form (/evidences) i dont have access information the firt form.

For example.

Later press Enviar in the second form i need nombre.id and comp.idCompetencias. How to get information?

Comment: you can save csrf-token in the cookie

Comment: How ?  I dont know use cookie

Comment: you can read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395866/3562771