# Python - Update a user in Django 2.2

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.2) in which I have implemented models for multiple types of users by extending the base User model. Now I need to implement a way to allow the admin user to edit a user ( can't use the default Django admin). So, I have utilized the [MultiModelForm](https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html#) to combine multiple forms on a single template, on the get request the form is loading properly with data populated.
Here's what I have done so far:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=TITLE, blank=False)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=USER_TYPE, blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CHOICES, blank=False)
    contenst = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='nc')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)


class ContactPerson(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)
    contact_no = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Phone number must be entered in the'
                                                                   'format: \'+999999999\'. Up to 15 digits allowed.')
    collection_use_personal_data = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
```

**Here's the related `forms.py`:**

```
class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'name', 'title', 'gender', 'contenst',)

class UserCPForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactPerson
        fields = ('customer_id', 'contact_email', 'contact_no', 'collection_use_personal_data')


class EditUserCPForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'user': EditUserForm,
        'profile': UserCPForm
    }
```

**and here's my related `views.py`:**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    id = self.kwargs['id']
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        id = id
        u = User.objects.get(id=id)
        print(u.user_type)
        u_form = None
        elif u.user_type == 'ContactPerson':
            print(request.POST)
            u_form = EditUserCPForm(request.POST)
            # p_form = UserCPForm(request.POST['profile'])
            if u_form.is_valid():
                print('valid')
                user_form = u_form['user']
                profile_form = u_form['profile']
                ucp_obj = ContactPerson.objects.get(user__id=u.id)
                print(ucp_obj.user.email)
                ucp_obj.user.email = u_form.cleaned_data['user']['email']
                print(ucp_obj.user.email)
                ucp_obj.user.name = u_form.cleaned_data['user']['name']
                ucp_obj.user.title = u_form.cleaned_data['user']['title']
                ucp_obj.user.gender = u_form.cleaned_data['user']['gender']
                ucp_obj.user.contenst = u_form.cleaned_data['user']['contenst']
                ucp_obj.customer_id = u_form.cleaned_data['profile']['customer_id']
                ucp_obj.contact_email = u_form.cleaned_data['profile']['contact_email']
                ucp_obj.contact_no = u_form.cleaned_data['profile']['contact_no']
                ucp_obj.collection_use_personal_data = u_form.cleaned_data['profile']['collection_use_personal_data']
                ucp_obj.save()
                u_form.save(commit=False)
                print(ucp_obj.user.email)
                print(id)
                messages.success(request, 'success')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('dashboard:dashboard-home'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'not valid data')
                print(u_form.errors)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('dashboard:user-edit', u.id))

    else:
        messages.error(request, 'you are not allowed to do so!  ')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('dashboard:user-edit', id))
```

> When I edit any field from the template and submit the form, the form
>   redirects me to the `dashboard-home` with the `success` message but
>   the user in the database is not updating.
>   **what can be wrong here?**

Comment: why you pass false commit  `u_form.save(commit=False)` ? , also it is better to use CreatView CBV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is your not selecting the user from the database, i would have approached this the following way.

```
user_form = u_form['user']
profile_form = u_form['profile']

ucp_obj = ContactPerson.objects.get(user__id=u.id)

u.email = u_form.cleaned_data['user']['email']
u.name = u_form.cleaned_data['user']['name']
u.title = u_form.cleaned_data['user']['title']
u.gender = u_form.cleaned_data['user']['gender']
u.contenst = u_form.cleaned_data['user']['contenst']
u.save()

ucp_obj.customer_id = u_form.cleaned_data['profile']['customer_id']
ucp_obj.contact_email = u_form.cleaned_data['profile']['contact_email']
ucp_obj.contact_no = u_form.cleaned_data['profile']['contact_no']
ucp_obj.collection_use_personal_data = u_form.cleaned_data['profile']['collection_use_personal_data']

ucp_obj.user = u
ucp_obj.save()

messages.success(request, 'success')
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('dashboard:dashboard-home'))
```

...
Need to update EditUserCPForm instance as well..

```
    elif u.user_type == 'ContactPerson':
        print(request.POST)
        curr_user = User.objects.get(id=id)
        contact_person = ContactPerson.objects.get(user=u)
        print(u.user_type)
        u_form = EditUserCPForm(request.POST, instance={
            'user': curr_user,
            'profile': contact_person
        })
```

Comment: I have the url for `user-detail` as `re_path('user/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/detail/$', views.get_user_detail, name='user-detail'),` so I redirect it to that as `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('dashboard:user-edit', u.id))` it returns `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '10' does not appear to have any patterns in it`

Comment: Also, your code is working only if I change the email, if the change only other fields and keep the email as it is, it gives an error as `User with this Email already exists.`

Comment: i'm not really liking were we're heading with this, just brushing up on those small hiccups is gonna hurt your project overall, seems your user is being updated twice in the above case. regarding the path your model describes a different absolute url, i know this is not relevant in the url config case, but to me it seems like it's not a solid  structure.
would it be possible if i take a look at the overall project and make a pull request to help with these issues and define how we separate our logic and not just spread it around between forms views and models. (bad architecture)

Comment: can you put me your email address, so I will add you to the repository?

Comment: rajjix@rajjix.com

Comment: I have added you to the repository, accept the invitation sent to your inbox, please!