# Django, How to add two form in one page?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am new to django, my question is simple. How can I add two form in the same page? I tried many things as making a class in views or add a second urls path but didn't find how. Thanks you for helping

this is my code:

forms.py

```
class scrap_info(forms.Form):
    url = forms.CharField(label="Urls")
    website = forms.ChoiceField(label="Website", choices=ask_website)


class sms_info(forms.Form):
    data = forms.ChoiceField(label="Data list", choices=ask_data)
    number = forms.CharField(label="Sms number")
```

views.py

```
def scrap_app(request):
    form1 = scrap_info(request.POST or None)

    return render(request, "sms/scrap_app.html", {'form1': form1})


def sms_app(request):
    form2 = sms_info(request.POST or None)

    return render(request, "sms/sms_app.html", {"form2": form2})
```

scrap_app.html

```
<body>
<div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" value="Save">SCRAP</button>

    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("/scrap_app", views.scrap_app, name="scrap_app"),
]
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem just recently and I solved it by adding a hidden field on every form and getting that hidden value to determine what form was submitted by using an if condition in views

Here's how I did it using CBV.

***views.py***

```
class ContactUsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'yourtemplate.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        inquiry_form = InquiryForm(self.request.GET or None, prefix='inquiry_form')
        complaint_form = ComplaintForm(self.request.GET or None, prefix='complaint_form')
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['complaint_form'] = complaint_form
        context['inquiry_form'] = inquiry_form
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request):
        # instantiate all unique forms (using prefix) as unbound
        inquiry_form = InquiryForm(prefix='inquiry_form')
        complaint_form = ComplaintForm(prefix='complaint_form')

        # determine which form is submitting (based on hidden input called 'action')
        action = self.request.POST['action']

        # bind to POST and process the correct form
        if action == 'inquiry':
            inquiry_form = InquiryForm(data=request.POST, prefix='inquiry_form')
            if inquiry_form.is_valid():
                # Your logic here
                return self.render_to_response(
                    self.get_context_data(
                        inquiry_form=inquiry_form,
                        complaint_form=complaint_form,
                    )
                )
            messages.error(self.request,
                           'Inquiry form is invalid.')

        elif action == 'complaint':
            complaint_form = ComplaintForm(data=request.POST, prefix='complaint_form')
            if complaint_form.is_valid():
                # Your logic here
                return self.render_to_response(
                    self.get_context_data(
                        inquiry_form=inquiry_form,
                        complaint_form=complaint_form,
                    )
                )
            messages.error(self.request,
                           'Complaint form is invalid.')

        # prep context
        context = {
            'inquiry_form': inquiry_form,
            'complaint_form': complaint_form,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

***yourtemplate.html***

```
<!-- First Form -->
<form action="" method="post" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='inquiry'>
    {{ form1 }}
    <button type="submit" title="Send Inquiry">Send Inquiry</button>
</form>

<!-- Second Form -->
<form action="" method="post" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='complaint'>
    {{ form2 }}
    <button type="submit" title="Send Complaint">Send Complaint</button>
</form>
```

As you can see there's a hidden value in every form named '***action***', that will be the one to determine which form was submitted.