# Can I add 2 or more different forms in the same template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am new to Django and was working on a page where I need to allow the user to place a bid on an item, leave a comment or add/remove this item from his watchlist

so I thought I would need to have a form for each of these tasks, but all I found about multiple forms was formsets and that's not what I need.

So my question is how can I have more than 1 form in a template or what are the alternative ways to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As answered here:
[Proper way to handle multiple forms on one page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django)
You can read the submit data to find out which form was filled out or you can have two different views for the two forms by giving them different URL's in the action.