# Handling Multiple Forms on the Same Page in Django without Django's default model form

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to develop a webpage with two forms on the same page with **Django**. Anyone will able to fillup any single form and submit it, then that data will be saved in the database. Here I try to avoid Django's default model form and any type of js stuff also.

My **HTML**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- animated css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"/>

    <!-- font awsome css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- custom css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="row m-0 bg-info">
        <h2 class="mx-auto my-4">Multiple form in one page</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div style="height: 40px;"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid my-5">
        <div class="row m-0 d-flex justify-content-center">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>Employee Profile</h2>
                <form class="#" method="POST" id="EmployeeProfile">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Ranks</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ranks" placeholder="Enter ranks">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>salary</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="salary" placeholder="Enter salary">
                    </div>

                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2"></div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>Inspector Profile</h2>
                <form class="#" method="POST" id="InspectorProfile">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Ranks</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ranks" placeholder="Enter ranks">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Your email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email">
                    </div>

                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here how can I code my `views.py` with function based view to get data from this form? and how to determine which form sent me that data.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by setting different form action and by making different view for perticular form like this
inside your `template :`

```
 <form method="POST" action="{% url 'form1' %}">
    ........all input fields
    </form>
    
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'form2' %}">
    ........all input fields
    </form>
```

inside your `views.py :`

```
def form1(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
      ...get all values
      return render(request,'forms.html')

def form2(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
      ...get all values
      return render(request,'forms.html')
```

Comment: Merry Christmas @Kanchon Gharami

Comment: Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!