# I have 2 forms on the same page that uses django-recaptcha ReCaptchaV2Invisible, when I submit the "2nd" form the "1st form is submitted instead

Tags: django

Hi I have two forms on my home page, the one is a "contact form" and the other one is a "subscribe to mail list form". I used the "django-recaptcha ReCaptchaV2Invisible" field on both forms. The contact form works fine, but if I submit the second form (the mail list one) the first form is submitted and I get and invalid form error (obviously).

Has anyone experience the same problem? any recommended fixes?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your html code also so that we can help you better

Comment: refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395866/11544538)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.