# request.POST on multiple image buttons in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have django form which consist of two **image** buttons. Now how can i perform two different POST action based on specific **image** button clicked in views.py?

I followed the below link

[How can I build multiple submit buttons django form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866272/how-can-i-build-multiple-submit-buttons-django-form)

The above link will use **name** property of input tag and performs the action.

But this link will only describes about **submit** buttons but not about **image** buttons

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Image buttons work same as "normal" buttons. Just assign a name attribute as you would do with input type button.

The link you provide describes what to do.

Comment: if i add <input type="submit" name="add_skill" value="Add Skill" /> this will work.                                                     But if i add below mentioned image button then form will not POST.
<input type="image" src="/site_media/img/icons/add_image.gif"      name="add_skill" value="Add Skill" />                                                                   What is the difference between above two tags?