# Django getting right return value for post.request

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to get the product id using request.post in Django. I am currently testing using the console, but the only product_id value I am returned is 1.

This is the particular function in the view:

```
def test_view(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    my_carts_current_entries = Entry.objects.filter(cart=cart_obj)
    products = Product.objects.all()
    if request.POST:

        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        entry_quantity = request.POST.get('entry_quantity')

        product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)


        print(product_id)
        # print(entry_quantity)
        # Entry.objects.create(cart=cart_obj, product=product_obj, quantity=product_quantity)
    return render(request, 'carts/test.html', {'cart_obj': cart_obj, 'my_carts_current_entries': my_carts_current_entries,
                                              'products': products})
```

This is the html on the template.

```
<form method="POST">
    <br>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for product in products %}
    {{ product.name }} <br>
    <button>Add to Basket</button>
    {{ product.id }}
    <input type="hidden" name='product_id' value='{{ product.id }}'>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have as many `<input>` tags within 1 `<form>` as many products you have displayed. They all have the same name, so you always get the value of the first one.

I'd recommend getting rid of `<input>` and attaching the value of `product.id` to the button itself (or `<input type="submit">` to be exact). Here's the more descriptive explanation:
[How can I build multiple submit buttons django form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866272/how-can-i-build-multiple-submit-buttons-django-form)

An alternative would be to change your code to have multiple forms, like that:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ product.name }}
        <br/>
        <button>Add to Basket</button>
        {{ product.id }}
        <input type="hidden" name='product_id' value='{{ product.id }}'>
    </form>
    <br/>
{% endfor %}
```