# How to filter a list of posts based on category

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Hi I'm pretty new to django. I'm building my first web app and I've hit a bit of a snag.

I have a template that shows a paginated list of posts. I have a side bar which also dynamically populates a list of post categories:

```
{% for cat in category_count %}
<div class="item d-flex justify-content-between">
<a href="#">{{ cat.categories__title }}</a>
<span>{{ cat.categories__title__count }}</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to be able to click one of these categories and then display a filtered list of the posts by category. Categories are a Many to Many field of Posts.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    content = HTMLField()
    previous_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='previous', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    next_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='next', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

My idea was to create a url for 'category/' and have that display the filtered list, but I don't know how to set it up so that I can get the user's selected category from the request. Any ideas?

NOTE: If there's a better way to handle this that any of you have come across I'm completely open to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will do is to complete this action in two parts:

1. Display a list of buttons which sends data to the server about the choice
2. Return the filtered list (based on choice) back to the template

**Step 1**

Display a list of items and then put different choices in the `name` attribute for the Django server to read.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="choice_1" value="value1" />
  <input type="submit" name="choice_2" value="value2" />
</form>
```

**Step 2**

You return the queryset based on the user's choice. You should add this in your views or wherever you deem appropriate of handling these data.

```py
if 'choice_1' in request.POST:
    # return the queryset based on choice 1
elif 'choice_2' in request.POST:
    # return the queryset based on choice 2
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2011023/12467282).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag, along with `cat.id`:

```
{% for cat in category_count %}
<div class="item d-flex justify-content-between">
<a href="{% url 'post_view' cat.id %}">{{ cat.categories__title }}</a>
<span>{{ cat.categories__title__count }}</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now in your `urls.py` add a view named **post_view**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post', post_view, name='post_view'),
    ...
]
```

Finally, in your `views.py`, you can access the `category_id` as a function argument:

```
def post_view(request, category_id):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__id=category_id)

    ...
```

Comment: did you mean to type "{% url 'post_view' cat.id %}, or alternatively have the url/route be called "category_view"?

Comment: @Stephen sorry that was a typo.  It is supposed to be `post_view`