# My view doesn't save the instance from Form in Djagno

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying make a comment section for my Q&A project.I made the **model** for comment , the form part in **question_detail.html** an , also the **QuestionCommentForm()** in form.py .

model.py

```
class QuestionComment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = 
    models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200, null= True , 
    blank = True, default ='')
    def __str__(self):
    return str(self.body)
```

forms.py

```
          {%if c_form%}
    <form method="POST" action= "{% usl 'blog:question-commet' question.id  >{% csrf_token %}
    {{c_form.media}}
    {{ c_form.as_p}}
      <button type = "submit" , name = "question_id", value = "{{question.pk}}", class ="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">submit comment</button>
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def question_comment(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = QuestionCommentForm()
     print('finction comment started'*20)
     if request.method == 'POST':
        c_form = QuestionCommentForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():        
            new_comment = c_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.refresh_from_db()
            c_form.instance.user = request.user
            question = Question.objects.get(id = request.POST.get('question_id')

            new_comment.question = question
            new_comment.bldy =c_form.cleaned_data.get('body')
            new_comment.save()
    context['c_form'] = c_form
    return render(request, 'blog/question_detail.html',context)

class QuestionDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'blog/question_detail.html'
    model = Question
    context_object_name = 'question'
    count_hit = True
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(id = self.kwargs['pk'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        c_form = QuestionCommentForm()
        context = super(QuestionDetail,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.obj= get_object_or_404(Question, id = self.kwargs['pk'])
        self.object.save()
        self.object.refresh_from_db()
        answers = Answer.objects.filter (question_id = self.obj.id).order_by('-created_date')
        liked =self.obj.like.filter(id =self.request.user.id).exists()
        print('liked in class question not checked still' *10)
        comments= QuestionComment.objects.filter(question = self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['comments']= comments
        context["answers"]=answers
        context["liked "] = liked
        context['c_form'] = c_form
        return context

    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('post started'*100)
        c_form = QuestionCommentForm()
        c_form = QuestionCommentForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():        
            new_comment = c_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.refresh_from_db()
            new_comment.user = request.user
            new_comment.question = c_form.cleaned_data.get('question_id')
            new_comment.bldy =c_form.cleaned_data.get('body')
            new_comment.save()
            context['c_form'] = c_form
        else:
            c_form= QuestionCommentForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/question_detail.html',context)
```

url.py

```
...
path('question-comment/<int:pk>/', question_comment, name = 'question-comment'),
```

]

in my view, first I tried to use a another function to handle the comment, got no result and made a **def post()**
in the **class QuestionDetial()** , and still the form shows up but when I type something and hit the button , it refresh the page and nothing saves . I have already saved a comment using admin and it appears in the question-detail page. used print to find the bug, but it seems the **post()** in class and the **question_comment()** not being recall. searched a lot but no answer. (BTW I get no error except the NoReverseMatch that I fixed)

Comment: Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , the problem was that I had two form-tags in **question_detail** template and buy adding  comment form in the end of the template had 3 , but the problem was when I pressed the *submit comment* button the terminal showed this message

```
"POST /create-like/blog/answer/18/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

which was the form I had made for like function .(while my url was *question-comment*)
I accidentally forgot to close the *like-form tag* in template. so all I needed was putting a

```
 </form>
```

after the form block .
thank's Willem Van Onsem. it solved my post method error.
and these were very helpful

[Proper way to handle multiple forms on one page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django)

[How can I build multiple submit buttons django form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866272/how-can-i-build-multiple-submit-buttons-django-form)

Answer (score 1):

You never save the model object (not by the form, nor by the view). Furthermore the name of the method is `'POST'`, not `'Post'`:

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def question_comment(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = QuestionCommentForm()
    print('finction comment started'*20)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c_form = QuestionCommentForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():        
            c_form.instance.user = request.user
            c_form.save()
    context = {'c_form': c_form }
    return render(request, 'blog/question_detail.html',context)
```

Comment: Thank's but I had done that (.save() in the class) , and I changed it as you said now but still not saving , my print() functions are not working both in question_comment() and in post method in class QuestionComment .

Comment: @RoohollahMozaffari: no, since you still did not alter the `request.method == 'POST'` check, so the `if` logic is *never* performed. It would also error, since `request.Post` does *not* exist either.