# how to write a single view for 2 forms like signup and login in one html file

Tags: python, django, django-views

i have html file that contains both login and signup form

```
 <form method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
       {{ user_form.as_p }}
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" name = "first_name" required>
       <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid first name.</div>
       <input type="text" class="input-field" id="lastname" name = "last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
       <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid last name.</div>
    </form>
```

and a similar login form
how to write a single view for both of these forms using buttons
i have already seen [How can I build multiple submit buttons django form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866272/how-can-i-build-multiple-submit-buttons-django-form) this but i didn't found useful

```
def user_login:
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('submit') == 'name1':
        pass
    elif request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('submit') == 'name2':
        pass
```

in this how to write else code if request.method not POST for every form

Comment: Instead of `request.method.get['submit']` I believe perhaps you want to use `request.POST.get('submit')`? (`request.method` is really a string it does not make sense to use the `get` method there)

Comment: i mistakenly write that , it also not working can you suggest anysite for that code

Comment: My bad I just copied from your post. I meant to use the method not index it. I have edited the comment above.